# Median value of a function

Tags: integration, median

Let $f(x) = \log\left ( \frac{x}{x+5} \right )$

I would like to find the median for $f(x)$ over the interval [0,5]. In practice, I have been using [1e-10,5].

One way to find the median is to take the middle value of x over [0,5]. In my case, it would be 2.5. Hence, the median would be simply

$\log\left ( \frac{2.5}{7.5} \right )=-1.098612$

Another possible solution would be:

$\frac{\textrm{50 percent of the area}}{\textrm{total area}}= \frac{\int_{0}^{m}\log\left (\frac{x}{x+5}\right) dx}{\int_{0}^{5} \log\left (\frac{x}{x+5 }\right )dx}=0.5$

In other words, the median for the function is found with the value m that gives 50% of the area on the interval [0,5]. We can find it iteratively. Using R, I have got:

$\frac{\textrm{50 percent of the area}}{\textrm{total area}}=\frac{-3.465738}{-6.931473} =0.5$.

The value m that gives 50% of the area is 1.469077. Hence, the median for the function would be:

$\log\left ( \frac{1.469077}{1.469077+5} \right )=-1.482399$

Should both approaches give similar results? If not, which one would be correct?

Cheers!

Tyler

Comment: $\int_0^m \log(\frac{x}{x+5})dx$ diverges for all $m>0$, so that method doesn't make much sense.

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \log\left(\frac{x}{x + 5}\right) = -\infty$, so how are you hoping to find a median value for the function on the interval $[0,5]$?

Comment: In practice, I have been using [1e-10,5].

Comment: As you shrink that left side smaller and smaller, however, say to $[10^{-25}, 5]$, you'll see that your mean will go to $-\infty$.

Comment: True. I fully agree. However, the median should not be affected. Does that make sense?

Comment: No.. Not quite. At least not to me..Both the mean and the median should move down to $-\infty$

Comment: Thank you so much, Lorenzo and AlkaKadri for your comments.  Let me try to reformulate the problem:  Let $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+5} $
Taking the median value over [0,5], we would have:
$\frac{2.5}{7.5}= 0.33333$

Another possible solution would be:

$\frac{\textrm{50 percent of the area}}{\textrm{total area}}= \frac{\int_{0}^{m}\frac{x}{x+5} dx}{\int_{0}^{5} \frac{x}{x+5 }dx}=0.5=$

$=\frac{0.767132}{1.534264} $. 

The value m for 50% of the area is 3.303068. Hence, the median  would be:
 
$ \frac{3.303068}{3.303068+5} =0.397813$
 
Should both approaches give similar results?